# Wrap each element and then prepend a new div to the wrapper?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery (3.1.1) to wrap elements of a given class and then prepend a new div as the first element inside the wrapper. I've tried a number of things and this is as close as I can get.

```
testWrap = function() {
    var testWrapImpl = function(index, value) {
        var div = $("<div></div>");
        $(value).wrap(div);
        $(div).prepend("<div class='child-div'>some text</div>");   
        alert("done");
    };
$(".myClass").each(testWrapImpl);
```

This code successfully wraps each element with the outer div but doesn't seem to do anything with the "some text" div.

The alert does show up for each of the elements in the page and the page seems to load with out error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `.prepend()` before using `.wrap()` to achieve what you're after.

Also, once you've defined `div` variable as a jQuery object, you should reference `div` variable rather than `$(div)`.

```
    var testWrapImpl = function(index, value) {
        $(value).wrap( '<div></div>' ).parent().prepend("<div class='child-div'>some text</div>");   
        alert("done");
    };
$(".myClass").each(testWrapImpl);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2966pxqz/4/

Comment: This may work for the OP, but the result is that the original element is wrapped inside the "some text" `<div>`. The `.wrap()` API puts the target inside the innermost element of the wrapper structure.

Comment: I just got through looking at it in the developer tab, but I'll look again.

Comment: @Pointy is correct, this may not achieve the desired result !

Comment: This worked for me.  Is it possible this solution is browser specific and that's why it's not working for some?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.  The prepend function WRAPS the .myClass element.  It does not add the "some text" DIV to the beginning of the .myClass element.  It prepends the contents of the "some text" div before "some text" then includes the .myClass content, then closes the "some text" div.

Comment: @John well it may look like it works on the screen, and the results may suit your needs, but your wrapped "myClass" `<div>` elements are ending up **inside** the "some text" `<div>` elements.

Comment: @John, pointy the updated fiddle and code block above does as John has intended

Comment: This code: $(value).wrap( '<div></div>' ).prepend("<div class='child-div'>some text</div>"); seems to prepend the "some text" div to $(value).  I need to prepend to '<div></div>'.

Comment: @John oh I see! You can do that by referencing the `.parent()` as indicated above.

Comment: Yup, adding .parent() to what I had gave me exactly what I needed.  Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

The `.wrap()` method wraps a **copy** of the wrapper around each target element. Thus once you've called `.wrap()`, your `div` thing is a perfectly OK element but it's not the actual wrapper.

What you could do is add a class to the wrapper, do the wrapping, then find the wrappers and add the extra element:

```
$(".myClass")
    .wrap("<div class='wrapper'></div>")
    .closest(".wrapper")
    .prepend("<div class='child-div'>some text</div>");
```

There's no real need to do your own `.each()` iteration; the jQuery routines will do that implicitly. If you need to make decisions about the wrapper for each element in "myClass", you can pass a function to `.wrap()`. The function will be called for each individual element with a single argument containing the index into the list, and with `this` bound to the element for that iteration. Your code in the function can inspect the element or do whatever, and the return value from the function will be used as the wrapper. So for example to give a numbered class to each wrapper:

```
$(".myClass")
    .wrap(function(index) {
      return "<div class='wrapper wrapper-" + index + "'></div>";
    })
    .closest(".wrapper")
    .prepend("<div class='child-div'>some text</div>");
```

Comment: I'd prefer to iterate through each item myself as (1) I need to do specific actions to individual elements, e.g. add a different guid to each element, or possible take a conditional action if the element meets some criterion.  Is there a way to do this with the implicit calls? And (2) I'm a long in the tooth Java guy so its hard for me to change the way I think about this stuff ;)

Comment: Well note that you can also pass a function to `.wrap()`. jQuery will pass that function the index into the original target list, and `this` will refer to the target element for that invocation. The return value from the function should be the wrapper to use for that element. I'll extend the answer to clarify.